# kube-up.sh fails on ubuntu 14.04 with some dzdo(sudo ) issue

Tags: kubernetes

flanneld                                                                                                                                                                  100% 2131     2.1KB/s   00:00
+ NEED_RECONFIG_DOCKER=true
+ CNI_PLUGIN_CONF=
+ EXTRA_SANS=(IP:${MASTER_IP} IP:${SERVICE_CLUSTER_IP_RANGE%.*}.1 DNS:kubernetes DNS:kubernetes.default DNS:kubernetes.default.svc DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local)
++ tr ' ' ,
++ echo IP:10.204.22.202 IP:192.168.3.1 DNS:kubernetes DNS:kubernetes.default DNS:kubernetes.default.svc DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
+ EXTRA_SANS=IP:10.204.22.202,IP:192.168.3.1,DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local
+ BASH_DEBUG_FLAGS=true
+ [[ false == \t\r\u\e ]]
+ ssh -oStrictHostKeyChecking=no -oUserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -oLogLevel=ERROR -t karan.singhal@10.204.22.202 '
    set +e
    true
    source ~/kube/util.sh

```
setClusterInfo
create-etcd-opts '\''10.204.22.202'\''
create-kube-apiserver-opts       '\''192.168.3.0/24'\''       '\''NamespaceLifecycle,LimitRanger,ServiceAccount,ResourceQuota,SecurityContextDeny'\''       '\''30000-32767'\''       '\''10.204.22.202'\''
create-kube-controller-manager-opts '\''10.204.22.202'\''
create-kube-scheduler-opts
create-kubelet-opts       '\''10.204.22.202'\''       '\''10.204.22.202'\''       '\''192.168.3.10'\''       '\''cluster.local'\''       '\'''\''       '\'''\''
create-kube-proxy-opts       '\''10.204.22.202'\''       '\''10.204.22.202'\''       '\'''\''
create-flanneld-opts '\''127.0.0.1'\'' '\''10.204.22.202'\''

FLANNEL_OTHER_NET_CONFIG= sudo -E -p '\''[sudo] password to start master: '\'' -- /bin/bash -ce '\'' 
  cp ~/kube/default/* /etc/default/
  cp ~/kube/init_conf/* /etc/init/
  cp ~/kube/init_scripts/* /etc/init.d/

  groupadd -f -r kube-cert
   DEBUG='\''false'\'' ~/kube/make-ca-cert.sh "10.204.22.202" "IP:10.204.22.202,IP:192.168.3.1,DNS:kubernetes,DNS:kubernetes.default,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc,DNS:kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local"
  mkdir -p /opt/bin/
  cp ~/kube/master/* /opt/bin/
  cp ~/kube/minion/* /opt/bin/

  service etcd start
  echo Deploying' master and node on machine....................................... true 'failed
  if true; then FLANNEL_NET="172.16.0.0/16" KUBE_CONFIG_FILE="./../cluster/../cluster/ubuntu/config-default.sh" DOCKER_OPTS="" ~/kube/reconfDocker.sh ai; fi
  '\'''
```

usage: dzdo -K | -k | -V
usage: dzdo -v [-AknS] [-p prompt]
usage: dzdo -l[l] [-AknS] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [command]
usage: dzdo [-AbHknPS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] [-g groupname|#gid] [VAR=value] [-i|-s] []
usage: dzdo -e [-AknS] [-C fd] [-g groupname|#gid] [-p prompt] [-u user name|#uid] file ...
usage: dzdo -h [user@] [-W,ssh-option] 
usage: dzdo --help

Answer (score 0):

There are [a](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/ubuntu/util.sh#L485) [few](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/ubuntu/util.sh#L570) [places](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/ubuntu/util.sh#L672) in the kube-up Ubuntu scripts where `sudo -E` is used. If you've aliased `sudo` to `dzdo`, I'm guessing that won't work (I don't see a `-E` option in that usage output).

You can try to get those scripts to work for you locally, and then feel free to send a PR.

Comment: Hi, CJ I have not aliased sudo to dzdo. I am adding the output of script below in debug mode.

Comment: Hmmm. Something (I'm not sure what) is running `dzdo` in an invalid way. I can't tell from your output where that is happening.